# Including files in Sass as opposed to scss

Tags: sass

I'm thinking of changing from SCSS syntax over to SASS.

The one thing I'm unclear on is how to import other files, as there seems to be a very large lack of guides for SASS as opposed to SCSS.

In scss I right the following for my main.scss

```
@include "folder/_file.scss";
```

So in sass, would that be

```
+'folder/_file.sass'
```

Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Did you try anything?  Try reading the documentation maybe?

Comment: All documentation I can find is written in scss format.

Comment: You aren't looking very hard then.

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html a little less than half way down the page is the section on includes and partials. All of it written in scss. And every youtube video I watch on the subject also uses scss. The only one I really found that doesn't is DevTips, but he doesn't really have an in depth tutorial on it that I've seen

I've googled how to include partials in sass and all it brings up is guides on scss format.

Comment: There is an entire [section on syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#syntax) that you completely skipped over.

Comment: I apologize, but I figured when I saw the section on includes that it would be in there.

Comment: Yeah, shame on you for thinking that a demo of both syntax for import would actually be shown IN the import section of the documentation, ya know, like most documentation does and should. /endsarcasm

Answer (score 1):

From the [official Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#_import):

> ## @import
>
> The @import directive in Sass does not require quotes, although they
> may be used. For example, this SCSS:
>
> ```
> @import "themes/dark";
> @import "font.sass";
> ```
>
> would be this Sass:
>
> ```
> @import themes/dark
> @import font.sass
> ```